# Vue.js - Best practice to interpolate data value in console.log object inside methods function?

Tags: javascript

How can I interpolate text string in nested array to `console.log()`?

Example:

```html
<template>
  <div id="myNavigation">
    <div
      class="button_link"
      v-for="(click) in items"
      :key="item.click"
    >
      <div
        class="home-navigation-item-component left-panel selected"
        @click="click = menuClickNavigation(click)"
      >
        {{ item.click }} <!-- Should show the data string -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

</template>

<script>
export default {
  data: () => ({
    items: [
      { click: 'click one' /* I want this to interpolate to console.log */ },
      { click: 'click two' /* This text string should show when a different element is clicked */ }
    ]
  }),
  methods: {
    menuClickNavigation (click) {
      this.click = (this.items.click)
      console.log(this.items.click) /* How to interpolate the items.click value? I want it to display "click one" in the console log function. */
    },
}
</script>
```

Console log displays `undefined` with current code because it's not interpolating to the desired data value text string in the nested array. Changing the interpolation method (which doesn't currently work because I have no idea how to make it work) with a text string, I get whatever is put in the `console.log()`, but I want the `console.log` to interpolate the corresponding text strings in the nested array of items.

Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you trying to access the value "click" from the `items` array? I think you should use `console.log(this.items[0].click)`.